# Problem with Kotlin inline class deserialization to JSON in tests

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

I'm trying to write tests for routes in a WebFlux application, but I encountered a problem. I got an error during parsing to JSON:

```
13:38:20.601 [parallel-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.server.handler.ResponseStatusExceptionHandler - [248c6c90] Resolved [ServerWebInputException: "400 BAD_REQUEST "Failed to read HTTP message"; nested exception is org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Cannot construct instance of `com.test.GetItemRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.test.GetItemRequest` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBuffer$DefaultDataBufferInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]"] for HTTP POST /v1/download
```

I have a request that uses an inline class:

```
@JvmInline
value class ItemName(val rawValue: String)

data class GetItemRequest(val name: ItemName)
```

The test:

```
    @Test
    fun `Request is parsed successfully`() {
        //...

        val client = WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(router.eimApiRoutes()).build()

        val request = """{"name":"item1"}"""

        val resp = client
            .post()
            .uri(EimApiRouter.DOWNLOAD_PATH)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(Mono.just(request), String::class.java)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk
            .expectBody()
            .returnResult()
            .responseBody

        val expectedResponse = "OK"

        assertEquals(expectedResponse, String(resp!!))
    }
```

I can work the problem around by adding a default constructor:

```
data class GetItemRequest(val name: ItemName) {
    constructor() : this(ItemName(""))
}
```

When I change the type of the parameter to String, it works.

**The question:**
Could somebody give the real solution? Maybe there is something missing in the test web client configuration (I tried to configure the Kotlin codecs manually, but without success)?

Comment: Are you using Jackson? Did you add `jackson-module-kotlin`?

Comment: Yes. Also I tried to create the mapper and register the codecs with references to the mapper in the WebTestClient builder, but with no success.

Comment: This is a known bug afaict https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/413 I vaguely remember running into this in the past, I think I added a default constructor to fix it